# How to add "changeable" element to javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I want to get number from html to javascript (id);

```
<script>
function ray_olcu_hesabi(id) 
{
var raypb_"id"   = document.getElementById(id).value ;
alert (raypb_"id");
}
</script>
```

AS below , I get id number to javascript , it is ok but I cant use it like the code below.

I have a lot of id number like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and all of their values are different , I want to get the value of which change and than ; use that changed element to do anotherthing... othervise I need to write same code for all of id numbers..

Thanks

Comment: First of, variable names cannot contain " characters. Secondly, what exactly are you trying to do and how *exactly* is that different from what your code currently does?

Comment: I have a lot of id number like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
and all of their values are different , I want to get the value of which change and than ;

use that changed element to do anotherthing... othervise I need to write same code for all of id numbers...

Comment: Please edit your question with that information

Comment: Many times when there's a bunch of variables with appended numbers/strings/etc. that are closely related what you want is an array or object (or `Map` etc). Without context it's difficult to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's possible with object like this:

```
let id = 2;
let obj = {};
obj["one" + id] = "something";
console.log(obj.one2); // something
```

And to create variable dynamically:

```
let id = 2;
eval('two'+id+'= "stringValue";'); 
console.log(two2); //stringValue
```

And last option:

```
let id = 2;
var result = 'valString';
eval('three'+id+'= '+"eval('result')"+';'); //important difference btw '' and ""
console.log(three2); //valString
```